# getting links including outer html

Tags: shell-script

From a html page with lots of links, I'm looking for a way to extract only the links that follow a specific format.

```
<a href="https://always/same/link/same-name_19.html">always same text</a>
<a href="https://always/same/link/same-name_18.html">always same text</a>
<a href="https://always/same/link/same-name_17.html">always same text</a>
```

I have found many solutions using `grep`, `sed`, and others but they all only return the inner links without the html tags and the "always same text" part.

It should work from the command line / bash script, I'm using Debian Jessie. 
the solution doesn't need to be a oneliner.

### update

the script i made with help of Ryan's Answer.

```
Curl=https://always/same/link/
filename=same-name

page=`curl "$Curl$filename"`
echo $page > $filename.curl

Gurl=https://always/same/link/

# working
link=`grep -Eo '<a href="https://always/same/link/same-name_([0-9]+)\.html">always same text</a>' $filename.curl | sort | tail -n1` 

# not working; $link will be empty
link=`grep -Eo "<a href=\"https://always/same/link/same-name_([0-9]+)\.html\">always same text</a>" $filename.curl | sort | tail -n1` 

# not working; $link will be empty
link=`grep -Eo "<a href=\"${Gurl}${filename}_([0-9]+)\.html\">always same text</a>" $filename.curl | sort | tail -n1` 

# what i ended up using.
link=`grep -Eo '<a href="'${Gurl}${filename}'_([0-9]+)\.html\">always same text</a>' $filename.curl | sort | tail -n1` 
echo $link | grep -o 'https:.*[.]html'
```

Comment: Based on the last part of your update (`echo $link | grep -o 'https:.*[.]html'`), was the real goal of this to extract *just* the URL of the link (the href attribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming most of the href attribute are always the same, and the inner-text are always the same, and you have an HTML source file, then something like this should work:

```
grep -Eo '<a href="https://always/same/link/same-name_([0-9]+)\.html">always same text</a>' HTML-source-file
```

`grep` will search through the `HTML-source-file` for the given pattern `https://always/same/link/same-name_([0-9]+)\.html`.  This pattern will match any string made up of the following elements, in order:

1. https://always/same/link/same-name_
2. any number of the digits 0 through 9
3. .html

The `-E` flag tells `grep` to interpret the pattern as an extended regular expression.

The `-o` flag tell `grep` to only output the text that matches the pattern.

To use variables, you can use double quotes around the regular expression, escape the double quotes *inside* the regular expression with backslashes, and enclose the variable names in curly braces, like so:

```
$ link_path=https://always/same/link/
$ link_name=same-name
$ grep -Eo "<a href=\"${link_path}${link_name}_([0-9]+)\.html\">always same text</a>" HTML-source-file
```

If, for some reason, the above `grep` with escaped double-quotes does not work, you can also use this:

```
$ link_path=https://always/same/link/
$ link_name=same-name
$ grep -Eo '<a href="'${link_path}${link_name}'_([0-9]+)\.html">always same text</a>' HTML-source-file
```

Comment: thanks (i seem to not have enough reputation point to give you a +1). when i first read your answer i was afraid it wouldn't work because these links are not on separate lines. but it turns out that it works just fine... thanks.. by the way what does the \ before .html do?

Comment: @Ricky Yeah, I wasn't sure if it would work if the links were not all on separate lines. However, after some testing, I determined that it would be fine even if they were on the same line. The ` \ ` before the `.` escapes the `.` so that it represents a *literal* period/dot character. Otherwise, the dot in a regular expression pattern is a wildcard that matches anything.

Comment: when trying to integrate this into my script, I'm running into a problem. the grep statement is between single quotes. not allowing to add in variables.. any change on adding these 2 variables into the grep statement? 

path=http s://always/same/link/
name=same-name

Comment: Ah. Didn't know you were going to use variables. Give me a moment, and I'll provide an update.

Comment: thanks Ryan.. you have been great help, your last update wasn't working for me.. but after bit of playing around i finally manage to get it working.. maybe you want to add it into the answer just in case others want to use it... '<a href=\'${Gurl}${filename}'_([0-9]+)\.html\">always same text</a>'

Comment: I made a mistake in my variable names, which I've fixed. Otherwise, not sure why it failed for you. I tested with Bash 4.3.42(5) and grep 2.24. I don't see how the regular expression you've provided in your comment would work, since it's missing the starting double-quote for the href attribute and it's got an unescaped single-quote in the middle of it. If it *did* somehow work for you, could you should the full command that you used and its output?

Comment: you where right about the missing double-quote, i really don't know what should or shouldn't work or why it did not work for me.. the unescaped single-quote is what worked for me... the full command i used, i edited into my question.  the output is the link that contains the highest number. thanks again...